# React router v6 param and nested routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I would like to use some nested routes with params in the middle

The routes i would like to be able to reach are :

```
/foo/:id/bar1
/foo/:id/bar2
/foo/:id/bar3
```

My routing is

```
<Route path="foo" element={<Foo />}>
  <Route path=":id">
     <Route path="bar1" element={<Bar1 />}>
     <Route path="bar2" element={<Bar2 />}>
     <Route path="bar3" element={<Bar3 />}>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

(**Foo** does have an `<Outlet />` component).

But when i access `/foo/42/bar1` i got **No routes matched location**

Also I would like to be able to access `/foo` without id and nested routes. But when I do so i also got **No routes matched location.**

Finally I would like to define `/foo/:id/prono` as index, that means `/foo/:id` should redirect to it.

How can I achieve all of this ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any overt issues with your code, and copy/pasting it into a running codesandbox doesn't reproduce the errors you describe.

Even so, here's a routing suggestion:

```
<Route path="foo" element={<Foo />}>
  <Route path=":id">
    {/* Index route redirects to "prono" */}
    <Route index element={<Navigate to="prono" replace />} />

    <Route path="bar1" element={<Bar1 />} />
    <Route path="bar2" element={<Bar2 />} />
    <Route path="bar3" element={<Bar3 />} />
    <Route path="prono" element={<Prono />} />

    {/* Unknown paths redirect to index route */}
    <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="." replace />} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

[image: Edit react-router-v6-param-and-nested-routes]

Comment: how would you validate and possibly navigate to a 404 page if a :id does not have a certain Bar? e.g. if /999/Bar3 does not exist but /99/Bar3 does? I am trying to find a good solution to navigate to 404 pages when url with several :params might have matches that do not exist as data.

Comment: @RemEmber Create a layout route component that reads and validates the `id` route path param in a `useEffect` hook and redirects off the route if it isn't valid.

Comment: @RemEmber Sorry, I was mobile earlier. Would you like to see an example of the suggested wrapper/layout component to validate path params above? Can you provide an example of valid/invalid `id` path parameters?

Comment: I think this would be a minimal example: /999/Bar3 does not exist but /99/Bar3 does exist. In reality the url are even longer e.g. /98/pub/Bar2/drink/7 and I would like to handle that  Bar3 has no drink 7 but in general drink 7 exists, but only in Bar2. I hope that makes sense. What I dont like about the layout component is that it needs to know information from all parents. It needs to validate the 98 has a Bar2 and that Bar2 has a drink 7. But I can also see how there might not be a more elegant way. Thank you for your thoughts!

Comment: Is that maybe something that should be handled by the backend with a redirect 302? But that also does not really work, because then the backend needs to validate the request urls.

Comment: @RemEmber I think you've misunderstood the purpose of the layout routes a bit. They serve only to help organize the routes and based on the dynamic route path params. The params would typically be validated in the component being rendered on any specific route. All the params for the entire path are collected up into the `params` object, so there's no need to do "partial" validation in any of the intermediate layout routes. Does this make sense? If you don't mind can you edit your post to include a more representative code example?

Answer (score 0):

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-smoke-t2rfdt?file=/src/App.js:0-1463)

I only show the `id` in Bar1, but you can do the same in the other components to see where you came from. And maybe `<Route index element={<Prono />} />` should just Navigate to 'Promo'...

```
import "./styles.css";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Navigate,
  Outlet,
  useParams,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

const Foo = () => (
  <div>
    I am the foo component.
    <div>
      <Link to="/foo"><a>goto foo</a></Link><br />
      <Link to="43"><a>goto 43</a></Link><br />
      <Link to="43/bar1"><a>goto 43/Bar1</a></Link><br />
      <Link to="43/bar2"><a>goto 43/Bar2</a></Link>
    </div>
    <Outlet />
  </div>
);

const Prono = () => <div>I am Prono, hear me roar.</div>;
const Bar1 = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return (
    <>
      <div>I am the bar1 component.</div>
      <div>My id is {id}</div>
    </>
  );
};
const Bar2 = () => <div>I am the bar2 component.</div>;
const Bar3 = () => <div>I am the bar3 component.</div>;

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to={"/foo"} replace />} />
      <Route path="foo" element={<Foo />}>
        <Route path=":id">
          <Route index element={<Prono />} />
          <Route path="prono" element={<Prono />} />
          <Route path="bar1" element={<Bar1 />} />
          <Route path="bar2" element={<Bar2 />} />
          <Route path="bar3" element={<Bar3 />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}

const AppWithRouter = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
export default AppWithRouter;
```